# Why doesn't calling next within a rescue block within a transaction within a loop work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, transactions

I have a loop like this:

```
# Iterate a list of items
req_wf_list.each do |req_wf|
    # Begin a transaction
    ReqWf.transaction do # ReqWf is an ActiveRecord model class
        # Do some things
        # ...

        # 1. I want to be able to continue processing with the
        #    next iteration of the loop if there is an error here
        # 2. I also want to rollback the transaction associated with
        #    this particular iteration if I encounter an error
        begin
            # Do something that might return an error
        rescue
            # Do some error processing
            puts "Caught such and such error"

            # Don't complete transaction (rollback),
            # don't "do some more things",
            # proceed to next item in req_wf_list
            next
        end

        # Do some more things
        # Shouldn't make it here if there is an error but I do indeed make it here
        # ...

    # End transaction
    end

# End loop
end
```

Now, I would expect that calling "next" within the rescue block would cause the transaction associated with that particular iteration of the loop to rollback and for execution to resume at the top of the next iteration of the loop.  Instead, execution appears to resume at the "Do some more things" line.  It is as if the "next" statement is completely ignored.  What am I missing?

Comment: I tried a similar structure and `next` correctly exited the nearest enclosing block as expected. What kind of exception is being raised? Are you sure that your `rescue` is being entered?

Comment: @muistooshort The rescue is being entered. I have a `puts` in there and I am seeing that output on the console. Execution resumes immediately after the `end` statement for the transaction's block.

I previously had a bit of code just after the end of the transaction and just before the end of the loop and I have now moved that code to the inside of the transaction. That will probably fix things. I'm still surprised, however, that the `next` statement was handled by the containing transaction block and not the loop's block.

Comment: `each` is really nothing special as far as Ruby is concerned, it is just a method that takes a block and just happens to execute that block in a loop-like fashion. Ruby doesn't know that `each` is loop-ish. `next` simply exits the current block and that's exactly the behavior I see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely that in this case next applies to transaction so you are in a nested loop situation.

This is an example of what can be done to solve the issue

```
req_wf_list.each do |req_wf|
  catch :go_here do  #:missingyear acts as a label
    ReqWf.transaction do

      throw :go_here unless something  #break out of two loops

    end
  end #You end up here if :go_here is thrown
end
```

But in general, it is not a good practice to use `next`. You should be able to put a global begin .. rescue and have all the conditions inside of it, so that nothing else gets executed once you catch an error.

**Update**

I did some a small test and the behavior is as you expect it.

```
loop = [1,2,3]
loop.each do |value|
  puts "value => #{value}"
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    puts "Start transaction"
    begin
      raise 
    rescue 
      puts "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid"
      next
    end
    puts "Should not get here!"
  end
end
```

The output is the following:

```
value => 1
Start transaction
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid

value => 2
Start transaction
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid

value => 3
Start transaction
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
```

Is it possible that you had another error in your code before the `next` was being called ?

In any case, using the `next` statement is not the best option as I said before.

Comment: Everything you said makes sense and I think I will change my code to follow the model that you suggested. My follow-on question, however, is how can there be something "next" to do in a transaction? In other others, why does a transaction present itself as a loop and not simply as another block (i.e. the same way that the begin..rescue..end block works)?